# Create enum instance by string in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

I am trying to extract the enum members of a numeric enum in typescript, but window[name] does return an undefined object.

```
export enum MyEnum {    
  MemberOne = 0,   
  MemberTwo = 1
}

export class ObjectUtils {
  public static GetEnumMembers(name: string): Array<string> {
    let enumInstance = window[name];

    return Object.keys(enumInstance).map((k: any) => enumInstance[k]).filter((x: any) => typeof (x) == "string");
  }
}
```

So now I call the GetEnumMembers method like this:

ObjectUtils.GetEnumMembers("MyEnum");

enumInstance results undefined.

**edit:**
I want to return a string array with ["MemberOne", "MemberTwo"]

Comment: Please provide a minimal but complete example of what you're doing. The provided code snippet leaves questions unanswered.

Comment: Can you make sure that whatever `window[name]` is, that it's not `undefined`?

Comment: `window.MyEnum` is undefined, because exports are not stored on `window`. Check the JavaScript code the TypeScript compiler is generating.

Comment: Sorry, but do you have any idea how to solve my issue?

Comment: you could pass in the enum itself, instead of only its name. not sure though if that's an option for you.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? I have the same sort of function that accepts a string argument & needs to determine if an enum with that name exists so it can return an array of its member values. Passing the enum type itself works, but requires extra imports.

Answer (score 0):

Exported members won't be added to `window` unless you add them yourself. You can refactor your code to accept the enum itself instead of the enum name:

```
export enum MyEnum {    
  MemberOne = 0,   
  MemberTwo = 1
}

// Some other file
import { MyEnum } from "./MyEnum"

class ObjectUtils {
  public static GetEnumMembers(e: {
    [key: string]: any
  }): Array<string> {
    return Object.keys(e).map((k: any) => e[k]).filter((x: any) => typeof (x) == "string");
  }
}

// And use it like:
console.log(ObjectUtils.GetEnumMembers(MyEnum));
```

Comment: The idea is to have generic function which accepts the string, because the enum type is extracted from a database so I do not know it at the programming-time.

Comment: @nicknack123123 You need to know where the enum is located. You can do this with a string as you have in you code, but the key is the location of the enum.